# Resizing <img> in Bootstrap carousel to parent element in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a dynamic page that has a carousel. I have no control of the images, because they are uploaded by the user. There are some guidelines, but I can't be sure that they are gonna follow them.

So, in my development tests, I have three images: a 100x100, a 2800x1500 and a 600x400

I want the carousel be in the middle of the page, and be responsive. I have no problem with that if I have more or less consistent images.

```
...
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <div class="carousel-img">
        <img src="img1.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="carousel-img">
        <img src="img2.png">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="carousel-img">
        <img src="img3.png">
    </div>
</div>
...
```

The CSS for "carousel-img" currently (I have tried lots of combinations, and nothing seems to work) is:

```
.carousel-img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-img img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Now, the very large image, works as intended. It resizes not using more than 400px vertically. The problem is with the other two images. The smallest one, resizes from 100px to 400px vertically and up to around 400px vertically, it doesn't fills up horizontally, despite the 100%.

So how can I tell CSS to resize the images (without changing aspect ratio) to use 100% of the parent container. Let me try to explain better: if the carousel is inside a `<div class="col-md-6">`, it should use all the width and up to 400px.

### Edit

Please accept my apologies to make everyone waste their time. There's no error in my original code. But there was a previous DIV before the carousel that read:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
```

I thought this might be no problem since it is intended to center the following DIVs, I don't know why but this `justify-content-center` prevented the images to resize appropriately, when I removed it, the images inside the carousel started working as intended.

Thank you very much to all who offered to help, today I learned something different.

Comment: Take a peak at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oyu9tf2r/ - The `100x100` fills up the entire container, horizontally *and* vertically. Is this not the behavior you're seeing in your own example?

Comment: how do you want to fit the parent's height and width without changing aspect ratio ?

Comment: Do you have any jQuery/JavaScript because you are asking for automatic reorientation of images. CSS is limited on what it can do. You need to detect the img in a "state" or have a condition met, so basically script.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap framework? If so, which version, and is it that you want images with any size to cover both the height and width of the carousel?

Comment: Yes, it's Bootstrap 4

Comment: @Susanoo you use `object-fit: cover;`

Comment: @Tyler yes, that's exactly what I want to do, but it doesn't work with Bootstrap 4, or inside the carousel.

Comment: You need the image in the background and use background-size: cover, or if you have a CMS like WordPress or something similar you can tell it to pre-crop your images to the right size you want. Img then needs to be in the background in the div, not an image inside it.

Comment: That could be another option, to pre-crop or pre-exapand the image so everyone is consistent... (I didn't want to do that, tho)

Comment: @Susanoo If a container was say `500 x 1200`, you could could scale up a `100 x 100` image to `1200 x 1200`. It would fill the container while maintaining its aspect ratio. Granted, a good chunk of the image would be cut-off, but OP seems to acknowledge/accept that outcome. My first comment on the post emulates this behavior, the issue instead being a matter of Bootstrap compatibility.

Comment: @zer00ne Not necessarily. See my comment above.

Comment: Yes, I prefered a "pixelated" image than a out of ratio image

Comment: @luisfer Can you explain why you can't use this with Bootstrap 4, or inside the carousel? If it's due to `object-fit`, I can replicate my exact example *without* using `object-fit` as well. I'm just wondering if I should post it as an answer or not.

Comment: I got no idea and that's what I'm trying to figure out. The carousel works fine, animation and everything, but the smaller image doesn't resize to fill up all the available space.

Answer (score 1):

Find a working snippet [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/vw71cbm2/18/) – this is using the carousel with indicators provided [in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-indicators) and the image sizes you  are considering.

The only changes you have to make is to remove your `carousel-img` div from your HTML, and change the `.carousel-img` rulesets in CSS to be applied to `carousel-item` instead:

```
...
<div class="carousel-item active">
    <img src="img1.png">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="img2.png">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="carousel-img">
        <img src="img3.png">
    </div>
</div>
...
```

And the CSS:

```
.carousel-item {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-item img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Have also removed the `active` class from all your items except the first as that would cause problems for Bootstrap JS to iterate through the slides.

You would have already got a first from me for using `object-fit: cover` from the start!

Comment: correct, the active in everyone was because I copied/pasted, I edited the question, thanks

Comment: Yes, but only after I made the change on the edit I mentioned. The problem wasn't in the carousel itself but on a previous div that was using `justify-content-center`. I still don't know why the images didn't resize correctly when this style was present.

Comment: Actually I think your question is still useful @luisfer, as other people might run in the same problem as you. Your initial code did not work and the solution I provided did – the fact that there was another problem in your code does not make your question insignificant. I'd recommend leaving it as it is.